# Setting baseURL for axios for use with Stripe / React

Tags: reactjs, axios, stripe-payments

Im currently trying to proccess payments using Stripe with react. However following the tutorial, i get an error 404 that my api/payment_intents is not found.

```
const stripe = new Stripe('here is my key');

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { amount } = req.body;
      // Psst. For production-ready applications we recommend not using the
      // amount directly from the client without verifying it first. This is to
      // prevent bad actors from changing the total amount on the client before
      // it gets sent to the server. A good approach is to send the quantity of
      // a uniquely identifiable product and calculate the total price server-side.
      // Then, you would only fulfill orders using the quantity you charged for.

      const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount,
        currency: "usd"
      });

      res.status(200).send(paymentIntent.client_secret);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
};
```

Here is the axios post

```
const { data: clientSecret } = await axios.post("../api/payment_intents", {
            amount: this.state.amount * 100
          });
```

I read in another post i need to set a baseURL but im unsure how to/what that even means. Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE: using "localhost:3000/api/payment_intents" i was able to get a different error message about CORS policy

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/api/payment_intents' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the baseURL like this:

```
let API = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://base_url/api"
})

export default API;
```

Then in your axios post:

```
const { data: clientSecret } = await API.post("/payment_intents", {
    amount: this.state.amount * 100
});
```

Normally, you would want to have the URL passed in as an environment variable also.

Comment: I still get an error saying not found even when using "http://localhost:3000/api/payment_intents"

Comment: can I see how you defined the base URL?

Comment: let API = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api"
}) there is an http:// before the localhost, but chrome displays as link, the api folder is in my root directory, does this need to be different?

Comment: you need to include the http://... baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api"

Comment: xhr.js:184 POST http://localhost:3000/api/payment_intents 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223183/discussion-between-cbm3333-and-lyndon).